# Jenkins error reading junit xml

Tags: xml, junit, jenkins

I am trying to make jenkins read a XML from junit, but I am getting the following error:

```
SEVERE: error while serving http://localhost:8080/job/JobTeste/test/trendMap
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testrun name="test" project="test" tests="19" started="19" failures="0" errors="0" ignored="0">
  <testsuite name="testEmail" time="22.51">
    <testcase name="testA_importBanc" classname="testEmail" time="12.53"/>
    <testcase name="testValidEmail" classname="testEmail" time="9.98"/>
  </testsuite>
</testrun>
```

Why it is happening?

Comment: Can you add how you have your Jenkins job configuration set up to point to the JUnit results file ?  There should be a path to the file in the "Publish JUnit test result report" under Post-build Actions.

Comment: I didn't write a path, I just entered the name of the file (for example, Test.xml), because this file is in the workspace folder of my jenkins job

Comment: Am I doing something wrong to load the xml files gareth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins uses the [Ant glob](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) format to locate your JUnit results file.  If the file is in a subdirectory under your workspace directory, you'll need to specify

```
**/Test.xml
```

or the full path to the file, relative to the workspace directory.

Comment: Thank for the answer gareth, but my files are already in the workspace root. So, I am trying to run `Test.xml , but I am not getting it

Comment: I got it! In the Job configutarion, I used the Result Seeking Strategy, and I use the JUnit class name. I didn't use the Publish JUnit test result report. And it worked!!